# How to implement CSS changes into the iFrame for Shopify Buy Button

Tags: html, css, shopify

I need to add the following styles to the iFrame of my buy button, but am unsure how to do this and am struggling to find articles that target these exact elements of the buy button. I do not want to disable the iFrame, I simply want to incorporate the following alterations to it:

```
.shopify-buy__layout-vertical {
    text-align: right;
}

.shopify-buy__option-select-wrapper {
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 42px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 85px;
}
```

Essentially when I open my buy button in FireFox I'm using the inspector tool to pick these two elements out from the live view and then altering the corresponding css that FireFox shows. Since I'm able to do this and it works correctly, I would imagine there would be a way to actually incorporate these changes in the code and save it, but have no idea how to approach that. I've attempted to simply add these two css elements onto my main css page, but it is not working.

Here is a JSFiddle showing the original buy button code along with the alterations in the css (the alterations are not actually working): https://jsfiddle.net/johnsmithh/eo4rzLwc/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot actually directly customize styles within the Shopify But Button iframe. But you can do that by passing configuration in the options parameter on initializing your component. For example, in your specific case where you want to adjust the wrapper element of your select box with variants, it would look something like that:

```
var options = {
  "option": {
    "styles": {
      "wrapper": {
        "border": "0px",
        "border-radius": "5px",
        "position": "fixed",
        "height": "42px",
        "bottom": "0px",
        "width": "85px"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information here: [Advanced customization](https://shopify.github.io/buy-button-js/advanced/), see **Custom styling** section.

And here are the elements you can customize: [Customization Options](https://shopify.github.io/buy-button-js/customization/), search for **Available keys**.

You can also consider disabling iframe as described in the last section on the [Advanced customization](https://shopify.github.io/buy-button-js/advanced/) page. It would allow you to customize styles directly as the component then will be rendered in your DOM.

Here's [an updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/VladimirC/d8jwsmbL/) based on your JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the option select alterations perfectly! Do you know how I could also style that layout vertical to make the text-align 'right'? This would fully resolve my issue :)

Comment: You can't customize styles for this element. Consider disabling iframe at all which will render the component in your DOM. It will give you full control of styling the rendered elements.

Comment: Thank you for this info. I've found a workaround, it involves using the following css instead... (modifying the buy button wrapper) .shopify-buy__btn-wrapper {
    margin-left: 85px;
} Is it possible to style this element?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Possible to incorporate the following? .shopify-buy__btn {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
padding-left: 36px;
padding-right: 36px;
}

Comment: Yes, you already have styles for the button in your code, adjust them.